# referencing an inner object in handlebar using a "key string"- property of the outer object

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I have this outer object containing an inner object in json format.

```js
{  
   "a":{  
      "b":{  
         "c":1
      }
   },
   "innerObjectName":"b"
}
```

I want to reference the innermost object c in my handlebars template by using the property innerObjectName.

This is what Im trying out:

```js
{{a["{{innerObjectName}}"]}}
```

but this template is not compiling. All I want to do is to use the innerObjectName property instead of writing a.b. How do I achieve this?

Is this possible in handlebars?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Never mind I hard coded it.